# Is the "owner" of a table/view/proc always a SCHEMA?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I did a lot of research on ownership chaining, but I am still not sure if I understood it.

So:  Is it correct to say that the "owner" of a table/view/proc is always a SCHEMA ?

If A.PROC accesses B.TABLE, but the user has only execute right on A.PROC, then the procedure will fail.  But if A.PROC accesses A.TABLE, then it will be executed ? Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. See [Ownership and User-Schema separation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669061.aspx):

> **By default**, when developers create objects in a schema, the objects are owned by the *security principal that owns the schema*, not the developer.
>
> ...
>
> A schema can also contain objects that are owned by different users and have more granular permissions than those assigned to the schema

And `ALTER AUTHORIZATION`:

> Beginning with SQL Server 2005, a user can own an OBJECT or TYPE that is contained by a schema owned by another database user. This is a change of behavior from earlier versions of SQL Server.

So, if `A.PROC` and `B.TABLE` are both owned by `D`, then ownership chaining means that security checks on `B.TABLE` will not take place. Conversely, if `A.PROC` is owned by `D` and `A.TABLE` is owned by `E` then ownership chaining doesn't apply and a permissions check will occur.

Comment: Oh well, I think now the puzzle gets complete and I begin to understand the core security concept.  Schemas are some sort of "containers", but no "principals". As a whole, there are PRINCIPALS (Users, Roles), "CONTAINERS" (Server, Database, Schema), and OBJECTS (Tables, Views, Procedures, etc).